# Configure OAuth token expiry duration on IBM MobileFirst Foundation Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

How to configure OAuth token expiry duration to a smaller value, e.g., 2 minutes, for adapters on a MobileFirst Foundation Server?

Answer (score 0):

The expiry value can be set by using  in the application's application-descriptor.xml file. The  element is optional and defines the         expiration period (in seconds) of OAuth access tokens. The default is 3600 seconds (one hour).

If the expiry has to be enforce on server side, as opposed to in the application, we can implement the following.

1. To pass validation, both a scope token and its containing token(access token) must not be expired.Each scope token (realm name) has its own expiration time, which can be different than the expiration time of the containing access token.The expiration period of a scope token (realm   name) is defined by the expirationInSeconds attribute of the login module that is associated with the realm whereas an access token contains the scope that is required by the application.It does contains 
   the realms which are defines in security tests.
2. Use the custom security test to protect the adapter.The scope of an access token must be pre-defined for this custom security test.The expiration period of a scope token (realm name) is defined by the expirationInSeconds attribute of the login module that is associated with the realm.

Please follow the below links to configure server side configuration for adapters.
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/authentication-security/using-mobilefirst-server-authenticate-external-resources/
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v700/mobilefirst_platform_foundation_doc.pdf